# phase detection with heterodyne method

Tags: fpga, optics-algorithm

I want to do phase detection by hydrodyne method on FPGA, but I don't know much about how to do it.

Can anyone help me? What I am looking for is to understand the algorithm of this method, the implementation requirements on FPGA and the requirements that must be followed in the code.